# How are sprites and graphics for high end graphic games made?

Tags: games, image-sprite, desktop

I have made small `HTML5` games and I use Inkscape to make the sprites.

But I'm curious to know how sprites and graphics for high end desktop games like NFS and Call Of Duty made.

Any answer or pointer for further reading is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! This question might do better at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: As it stands this question is very broad and wouldn't be a good candidate for migration based on what I'm seeing on gamedev. In general high end games use 3D suites like 3DSMax, Blender, or Maya even if they're then rendered to appear more cartoon than photorealistic. But its very broad because often the sprites are made up of hundreds of parts so I'm not sure what aspect you're asking about. This doesn't even take into account if you're asking about 3D engines like Unity3D. If you clarify and can be a bit more specific we can better decide to answer it here or try to migrate it.

Comment: I would migrate this to gamedev but after review it would appear that they already have a large number of those questions asked.  You can review the search results [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+tools+are+used+to+make+sprites).